# Sending Email via Outlook but after amount of emails it throws exceptions

Tags: c#, email, outlook, hotmail

I've recently created an web application in C# where I send emails to one mailbox. Everything works fine for the first 10 to 15 emails. After that, it gives the error :

> The Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.3 Requested
>   action aborted; user not authenticated

I then have to authenticate my email address again in order for it to work.
I use outlook/hotmail to send the emails.

Has any one ever had a similar issue?

Code Example

```
try
            {
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
                var mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.From = new MailAddress("email@outlook.com");
                mail.To.Add("thisemail@address.com");
                mail.Subject = "test1";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Body = "";
                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("address@outlook.com", "password");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                Response.Write("success");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: Code added to the question

Comment: Rises the question why you would want to spam emails to one mailingaddress... On topic: Did you validate/enable your email for SMTPAccess?

Comment: I did indeed validate the SMTPAccess. We've created surveys for a person that send the responses to that mail address. That person needs to monitor all incoming responses. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Take a look here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a75533eb-131b-4ff3-a3b2-b6df87c25cc8/how-do-i-send-mail-using-c?forum=netfxnetcom

Comment: Thanks. I got the problem solved without using 3rd party tools.